# Issues Creating Expandable Table iOS - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create an expandable table view, however when I click on one of the cells I load a .xib file to format the subviews, however when I click the cell again the .xib format remains and messes with the view of the cells. Is there a better way to make the expandable table view?

Code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 28;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {
            return [ticketList count];
        }
        return 1; // only top row showing
    }

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 72;
}
```

Load the xib here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"reuse"];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    NSLog(@"Number: %d", indexPath.section);
    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Cleanliness", @"Door", @"Peek Hole", @"Sink", @"Towel Rack", @"Closet", @"Carpet", @"Wall", @"Bed", @"Matress", @"Mattress Cover", @"Fridge", @"Blinds", @"Window", @"Screen", @"Air Conditioning", @"Chair", @"Desk", @"Garbage bin", @"Shelves", @"Phone", @"Jacks", @"Lights", @"Smoke Detector", @"Heat Detector", @"Light bulb", @"Deep Cleaning", @"Final Prep", nil];

    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        // first row
        cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.section]; // only top row showing

        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HelpDeskCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        HelpDeskCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[HelpDeskCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        CGFloat fontsize = 16;

        if([[[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"priority"] isEqualToString:@"Critical"]){

            [cell.IDLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else{
            [cell.IDLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.925 green:0.925 blue:0.925 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        [cell.IDLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];



        //reduce fontsize to 12 for the information labels
        //same on all devices and orientations
        fontsize = 12;

        //ticket status label
        [cell.statusLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.statusLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


        //ticket category label
        [cell.categoryLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [cell.categoryLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.categoryLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


        //ticket title label
        [cell.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        //Label holds the user that submitted the ticket
        [cell.submittedLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.submittedLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        //Label holds the user currently working on the ticket
        [cell.handleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontsize]];
        [cell.handleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        //ticket date label
        [cell.dateLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontsize]];



        // Set the text of the subviews
        NSString * ticketIdStr = [[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ticket_id"];
        [cell.IDLabel setText:ticketIdStr];
        NSString * ticketStatusStr = [[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"status"];
        [cell.statusLabel setText:ticketStatusStr];
        if([ticketStatusStr isEqualToString:@"Open"]) {
            [cell.statusLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.6 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else if ([ticketStatusStr isEqualToString:@"In Progress"]) {
            [cell.statusLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.733 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else if ([ticketStatusStr isEqualToString:@"Resolved"]) {
            [cell.statusLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.8 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else if ([ticketStatusStr isEqualToString:@"Closed"]) {
            [cell.statusLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        NSString * categoryStr = [[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"category"];
        [cell.categoryLabel setText:categoryStr];
        NSString * titleStr = [[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString * userIDStr = [[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"user_id"];
        NSString * handledByStr = [[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"handled_by"];
        [cell.titleLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@", titleStr]];
        [cell.submittedLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Submitted By: %@", userIDStr]];
        [cell.handleLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Handled By: %@", handledByStr]];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *orignalDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date_submitted"] substringToIndex:10]];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
        NSString * ticketDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:orignalDate];

        [cell.dateLabel setText:ticketDateStr];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Expand and Collapse here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

            }
            else
            {
                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            }

            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

            }
            else
            {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

            }
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}
```

*Update*

The main cell is a list of items and the expanding cell is suppose to be tickets from a sql database. I use a xib file to format the tickets

[image: xib file]

but when I collapse the cell which contains the items, this image remains and covers up the item cells

Comment: You will need to add an MCVE to this question to have any realistic hope of getting help. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: updated question

Comment: Can you post a simple project with what you're trying to do? Either on GitHub or zipped using some tile transfer service? Without seeing your xib and storyboard files, it's tough to tell just what may be going on.

Comment: The main issue is when i load the xib file I don't know how to remove it so it always remains in the table, even after the user collapses the cell. If i can remove the xib through code it would solve the problem

Comment: `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` has nothing to do with whether the cell was created purely through code, was a prototype cell in a storyboard, or was a xib file. If your code *correctly* deletes a row, and the content is still visible, then you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: One of the first things I'm noticing is that you call either `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` or `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, immediately followed by `reloadData`. That makes no sense. If you have removed elements from your data source, reloading the table view will not display them. So one would either delete and/or insert, ***or*** one would reloadData - but not both.

Comment: Yeah I added the reload data in the attempt to remove the xib from the tableview but it didnt fix the issue

Comment: If you make your project available, I'll take a look and see what's what. The snippets you have here are too disjointed.

Comment: added a final update, if youre still unable to understand the issue ill post the project.

Comment: It's not that I don't understand the issue... If I start a new project and create all the associated classes and data, and create a xib for the cell, and paste in the code you have here and try to figure out if everything is lined up... 1st - it's unlikely it will be an exact match, and 2nd - I'm not going to take that much time. If you post your project, I can load it, run it, step through, and fix it.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating expandable table view on clicking of UITableViewCell simply add a new cell in existing UITableView

[self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPath:indexPath
 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];