# How to remove nib (xib) from table through code- Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I load a xib file using

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HelpDeskCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

and was wondering if it is possible to remove it from the table through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's Docs (always a good first place to look):

> You may specify nil for nib if you want to unregister the nib from the specified reuse identifier.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614937-registernib

Comment: The program crashes when I cal nil. Could you explain how I would call it?

Comment: Where are you calling it? (and why?)

Comment: I'm trying to remove it from the table view. So I call it when the user collapses a cell. Also, do i call it the same way as i call a regular xib file, but instead use nil?

Comment: Hmmm??? Are you trying to remove a *cell* from the table? That has nothing to do with a nib being registered for reuse. Try rephrasing your question in terms of what you're trying to do...

Comment: I guess deleting nib isnt the best approach. I explain my issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804876/issues-creating-expandable-table-ios-objective-c.